# MYSQL automatically converting string to date when there is a '/'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table (`products`) from another table (`table 1`). The model number, however, has many symbols in it, including the '/'. The data exporting works quite fine, except the case when there is '/'. It converts it to a date instead.
E.g the following cases

```
11/08/1944 should be 11/08/44
11/07/1944 should be 11/07/44
```

The following is what I have:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `COL 1` AS id, `COL 7` AS model FROM `table 1` ORDER BY id ASC", $c2) or die(mysql_error());
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
    $id = $r['id'];
    $model = $r['model'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE products SET model = '".mysql_real_escape_string($model)."' WHERE id = $id", $c1);
    echo "MODEL: $model AND ID: $id <br />";
endwhile;
```

Comment: The column is of `DATE` or `DATETIME` type, isn't it?

Comment: no its a varchar, with length of 80. The other entries works fine. Just the ones with the '/' in it gets changed to a date.

Comment: Check if there are any before update triggers on the products table.

Comment: There were no triggers, it works after the escape. Thanks guys

Comment: This code itself cannot make the replacement you suffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try those :

- echo `$model` if its right .

  - look your column names if they are messed up.

Comment: No luck. Still the same problem.

Comment: try to print `$model` before you update and see if its right !

Comment: Sorry it's a problem in my end. It worked, it's just my column name was messed a bit, I figured it out now with the help of mysql_error(). Thank you